# How to loop over this API response object in React and get 'urls' link for image?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to loop over an Object in React, the object is being received from an API, I need to get the url 'regular' link. I have a state that sets the response from the API called 'searchImages',  I have been trying the following:

```
  {searchImages.map(item => (
       <img className='image-item' key={item.id} src={item.urls.regular} alt='cool' />
   ))}
```

but i get error: TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...searchImages.map...')

the actual object received from API is:
[image]

next level:

[image]

results level:

[image]

index 0 level:

[image]

urls level:

[image]

so I wanted to get the urls regular link for all results in the main results array.

if I haven't described something please let me know and I'll provide more info, otherwise any help would be appreciated.

I have called the API and then the response is set to state:

```
const [searchImages, setSearchImages] = useState([]);
    

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos/?client_id=btWDn-ckRUbNxJA&count=2&query=${searchInput}&per_page=2&orientation=landscape`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(images => setSearchImages(images));
    },[])
```

Comment: You need to show the code where you initialized or assigned `searchImages` variable. Btw, do not paste images into your question, that is [not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) the SO guideline.

Comment: well What is `searchImages` obviously not an array ... probably you want `searchImages.results.map(...)`

Comment: I get back a dict '{total: 6, total_pages: 3, results: Array}'

Answer (score 0):

From response you are setting json object in SearchImages instead of json array. So update your code which fetch images. Also make sure you set searchImages with blank array if response don't come.

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos/?client_id=btWDn-ckRUbNxJA&count=2&query=${searchInput}&per_page=2&orientation=landscape`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(images => setSearchImages(images.results));
},[]);
```

Comment: Tried that, but it still says 'TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'searchImages.results.map')'